# MULE: MYSQL CONNECTOR INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mule, mule-studio

MULE ESB 3.7 Community Edition, MYSQL DB Connector, Operation: Insert, Type: Parameter Anypoint Studio: Version: 5.4.0

MySQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VAR1,VAR2) VALUES (2,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VAR1= 2, VAR2 = 1;
```

`VAR1` is a Unique Key for the table. **It is NOT the primary key.**

**Problem**: The above query works perfectly well from MySQL Workbech. In Mule, all works well as long as there are no duplicate values for `VAR1` in the data. BUT If there is a duplicate value for `VAR1` in the data, then following error comes

> ERROR 2016-07-26 13:47:32,538
>   [[project1].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:
>
> Message : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'VAR1_KEY_UNIQUE'
>   (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException).
>   Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap Type :
>   org.mule.api.MessagingException Code : MULE_ERROR--2 JavaDoc :
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
>   Payload : {VAR1=55,VAR2=97} SQL Code : 1062 SQL State : 23000
>
> Exception stack is: 1. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'VAR1_UNIQUE'(SQL
>   Code: 1062, SQL State: + 23000)
>   (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl:-2 (null) 2. Duplicate entry
>   '1' for key 'VAR1_KEY_UNIQUE'
>   (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException).
>   Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap
>   (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>   org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor:93
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

**QUESTION**: How to make the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query work from Mule Anypoint Studio MySQL Connector?

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary bolding/uppercase and use appropriate formatting to make your post more readable.

Comment: this error says you have already an existing primary key value in your table. Check your code and avoid working like inserting a record in primary key field.

Comment: @reds - VAR1 is a Unique Key. It is not the primary key. As per business logic, it needs to be inserted or updated as the case may be. The query given above works when I use it via workbench but gives an error when processed via Mule (Anypoint Studio) using CE 37. I am not sure what is causing the error. Hence the post.

Comment: We could trace the error to definition of variables in the Mule Flow. This query works well with Insert parameter. This post can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can insert with duplicate key. please check SQL Query page, it might help you

[enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)